# Django Rest Framework: AssertionError

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with Django Rest Framework, I was learning to set ***permission and association*** to my API, and thus Im unable to run server so it says **AssertionError: Field(read_only=True) should be ReadOnlyField**

My model.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    owner=models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name='tasks')
    completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description=models.TextField()
```

serializer.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner=serializers.Field('owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields=('title','description','completed','owner ')
```

permission.py

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method is SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.owner==request.user
```

views.py

```
class TasksMixins(object):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class=TaskSerializer
    permission_classes=(IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def pre_save(self,obj):
        obj.owner=self.request.user

class TaskList(ListCreateAPIView):
    pass

class TaskDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    pass
```

Im not sure what I messed up. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem maybe with `owner.username` as I don't see how you can update this directly.

Try

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        read_only=('owner.username',)
        fields=('title','description','completed','owner.username')
```

Comment: help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69415844/response-returning-no-data-django-rest/69415870?noredirect=1#comment122692442_69415870

Answer (score 0):

The IsOwnerOrReadOnly class is trying to compare the attribute owner with the user logged, but in your serializer you only have the username not the user itself, you serializer should be like this:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_username=serializers.Field('owner.username', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields=('title','description','completed','owner', 'owner_username')
```

Also you need to validate if the object has the owner attribute:

```
class IsUserOwner(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method is SAFE_METHODS:
            if not hasattr(obj, 'owner'):
                return True

            return obj.owner == request.user
        return True
```

Comment: Im getting **TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'read_only'**