# response returning no data django-rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i don't know whats wrong with this code, previously i was getting assertion error and now this

```
class OrganisationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)   #manytomany field
    pictures = PicturesSerializer(source ='pictures_set',many=True)  #foreign key field
    class Meta:
        model = Organisation
        fields = ['name','address' ,'products','pictures']



@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request):
    data = None
    query_set = Organisation.objects.all()
    serialized_data = OrganisationSerializer(data = query_set,many =True)
    if serialized_data.is_valid():
        data = serialized_data.data
        print(data)
    return Response(data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**problem**

```
returning no data
```

Comment: That means that your `OrganisationSerializer` is not valid, but that should always be the case, since you did not bound it with request data.

Answer (score 0):

That means that your `OrganisationSerializer` is not valid, but that should always be the case, since you did not bound it with request data:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request):
    queryset = Organisation.objects.all()
    serializer = OrganisationSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

We thus use the `OrganisationSerializer` to convert model objects to data, not constructing `Organisation` objects from data from the request.

Comment: i still don't understand i thought they're used to convert, object instances to native types @Willem Van

Comment: @AtifShafi: yes, but the opposite direction as well: converting primitive types to `Organisation` objects (so deserializing). If you use this in serialization mode, then the serializer can not validate, since validation is only done to process primitive types to model objects.